# Setting the Angular Material Data Table Header Left CSS Property with ngStyle for Sticky Columns?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

In this demo I'm trying to set the `left` CSS property of the `CUSTOMER` `mat-header-cell` dynamically to `64px` using `ngStyle` but it looks like Angular overwrites the value with what it thinks it should be ... `216px` after the `ngStyle` update is applied.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-data-table-module-styling-sticky-column-adjust

Thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it is not taking 64px because of some default override.
In this case, we need to use left:64px !important.
But using '!important' is not supported when using ngStyle.
So, therefore we define a new class in the css file

```
    .leftMargin {
      left: 64px !important;
    }
```

and in the ngFor loop, we apply this css class only when the column name is 'customer'.

```
     <ng-container *ngFor="let c of COLUMNS" matColumnDef="{{c.toUpperCase()}}" [sticky]="isSticky(c)">
            <mat-header-cell [ngClass]="{'leftMargin': c=='CUSTOMER'}" [ngStyle]="styleHeaderCell(c)" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
              {{c.toUpperCase().split('_').join('')}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;">{{row[c.toLowerCase()] ? row[c.toLowerCase()] : row[c.toUpperCase()]}}
            </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
```

Refer to this stackblitz list: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-data-table-module-styling-sticky-column-cywshb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html